# How do we write a c++ program to control a bank account using classes?

Tags: c++, class, banking

I have to write the following program to control a bank account (as homework):

1. Create the program prototype using a named class Account. Each class is characterized by an owner name and balance.
2. The following banking operations should be added to the program: The owner can withdraw an amount from his account. Add account information. the owner can deposit an amount in his account. The owner can transfer an amount to another account. The owner can check the account balance.
3. In order to test the program the following program must be done: Create two Object account A1 and A2; Deposit 500 in A1. Deposit 200 in A2. Withdraw 100 from A1. Display the balance for A1. Withdraw 50 from A2. Display the balance for A2. Transfer 150 from A1 to A2.

Here is what I have done. I haven't added ant classes yet, it is quite uncompleted.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int password = 30718042;
    int OperationNumber, amount, CurrentBalance, AccountNumber, selection;
    cout <<"Welcome FATIH HANCER, please enter your password: ";
    cin >> password;

    while (password != 30718042) {
        cout <<"Please enter your password again. ";
        cin >> password;
    }

    while (password == 30718042) {
        cout <<"Please enter your operation number: "<<endl<<"1. Withdraw"<<endl<<"2. Deposit"<<endl<<"3. Transfer"<<endl<<"4. Check the balance"<<endl;
        cin >> OperationNumber;
        if (OperationNumber == 1) {
            cout <<"Please enter the amount you would like to withdraw. "<<endl;
            cin >> amount;
            int CurrentBalance -= amount;
            cout <<"Deposit action is completed. Your new balance is "<<CurrentBalance<<endl;
        }
        cout <<"\nIf there is another operation to do, please press 1. Otherwise, you will be redirected to the main menu. "<<endl;
        cin >> selection;
        if (selection != 1) {
            cout <<"Thank you for preferring us. "<<endl;
            break;
        } 
    }
    if (OperationNumber == 2) {
        cout <<"Please enter the amount you would like to deposit."<<endl;
        cin >> amount;
        int CurrentBalance += amount;
        cout <<"Deposit action is completed. Your new balance is "<<CurrentBalance<<endl;
    }
    if (OperationNumber == 3) {
        cout <<"Please enter the account number of whom you would like to transfer."<<endl;
        cin >> AccountNumber;
        while (AccountNumber == 30718059) {
            cout <<"Please enter the amount of money you would like to transfer to ABDULRAHMAN SUBH's account"<<endl;
            cin >> amount;
            int CurrentBalance -= amount;
            cout <<"Deposit action is completed. Your new balance is "<<CurrentBalance<<endl;
            break;
        };
    }

    while (AccountNumber != 30718059) {
        cout <<"The user couldn't be found. ";
        break;
    }

    if (OperationNumber == 4) {
        cout <<"Your balance is "<<CurrentBalance<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix `[Error] expected initializer before '-=' token`?
Besides, I want a balance being changeable by withdrawing, depositing and transferring money.

Answer (score 0):

```
int CurrentBalance -= amount;
```

You need to declare and initialize CurrentBalance variable e.g.

```
int CurrentBalance = 100;
CurrentBalance -= amount;
```

**-=** - this operation means `CurrentBalance = CurrentBalance - amount;`